# Replace Function Problems

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I wanted to change the names in my dataframe. I followed along with a tutorial, but for some reason, it would not work.

[image: my code]

Comment: Use: `df['first'].str.replace('jill', 'millie', case=False)`

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because you are trying to replace `jill`, but the name is actually `Jill`. Try this:

```py
df['first'] = df['first'].replace({'Jill': 'Millie'})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a replace regardless of the case, you can try:

```
 >> df['first'].str.lower().replace({'jill': 'Millie'})  # if you want to replace multiple values at once
```

or:

```
>> import re
>> df['first'].str.replace('jill', 'Millie', flags=re.I)  # one replace at a time
```

Comment: Thank you! I now have multiple ways to approach this problem.